# Параллельные вычисления на GPU: умножить на 3 все числа на входе

Tags: python, cuda

Есть видеокарта со следующими характеристиками (CPU-Z -> Advanced/CUDA):

> Processor Count = 4
>
> Cores per Processor = 48

Имеются данные в виде 192 (4*48) текстовых файлов, каждый из которых состоит из 100 строк вида `572452451` (целое число).

Необходимо выполнить умножение этих чисел на 3, используя параллельные вычисления на GPU. Результат нужен в виде такого же количества файлов с новыми данными.

Каким образом реализовать это на Python, используя CUDA драйвер или что-то подобное?

P.S. В первом комментарии по ссылке приведен интересный код:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy

mod = drv.SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
const int i = threadIdx.x;
dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(
drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b),
block=(400,1,1))

print dest-a*b
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/48798/

Comment: Есть подозрение, что так делать не стоит: вам придется гнать данные в GPU, потом обратно, а это затратная операция. При этом, сами вычисления будут занимать меньше времени, чем обмен данными.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: даже для одного числа: чтение с диска, преобразование из текстовой десятичной формы в long будет дольше чем `*3` операция.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, думаю, тут интересен сам процесс как загнать и умножить, а не выигрыш в производительности на конкретном упрощённом примере.

Comment: @Denis, мне кажется, что текстовые файлы в вопросе стоит заменить на массивы. Или надо преобразование из текста в числа тоже на GPU реализовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy верно, можно на примере массивов

Comment: [это может вас заинтересовать...](http://stsievert.com/blog/2016/07/01/numpy-gpu/)